# Cкрол изображения (Pixmap.scroll)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Доброго времени суток!

Я использую PyQt5 и хочу сделать скрол изображения на 26 пикселей по оси X

`pixmap.scroll(26, 0, pixmap.rect())`

Даный метод возвращает объект класса `QRegion()` и что с ним делать?.

Как мне установить новое изображение методом `setPixmap`?

UPD: У меня есть `QLabel` c `enterEvent` и `leaveEvent`. Задумка в том чтобы при наведении курсора на этот `QLabel` размером `26х26 px` изображение скролилось на 26 пикселей вправо. И обратно при отведении курсора от `QLabel`. Тем самым данная кнопка будет реагировать на курсор, изменяясь с красного крестика на белом фоне на белый крестик на красном фоне.

[image: изображение]

Comment: Предоставьте минимальный пример, а так чем является pixmap? Мб вам лучше использовать `QScrollArea`?

Comment: Немного обновил вопрос. Надеюсь, данного описания будет достаточно.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если вообще обойтись без `scroll`?

Подготовить 2 варианта состояния и переключаться между ними:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pixmap = QPixmap('52rQ3.png')
        self.pixmap_leave = self.pixmap.copy(0, 0, 26, 26)
        self.pixmap_enter = self.pixmap.copy(26, 0, 52, 26)

        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap_leave)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap_enter)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap_leave)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Label()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

**leave:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**enter:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за Вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Решил даный вопрос заданием отрицательного отступа при наведении на  `QLabel`.

`QLabel.setMargin(-26)`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#margin-prop